# Changing Song Length to a Number with Pyfoobar

Tags: python

While attempting to make a now playing script for foobar with [pyfoobar](https://code.google.com/p/pyfoobar/), I've been trying to convert the length of the current track, a string, into a regular integer.

```
from pyfoobar import foobar
import time

fb2k = foobar()
while(fb2k.isPlaying()==True):
    fb2k.playRandom()
    length=fb2k.lengthOfTrack()
    minute=int(length[0])*60
    second=int(length[2:])
    length=(minute+second)-1
    print "Now Playing: "+fb2k.getCurrentArtist()+" - "+fb2k.getCurrentTrack()
    time.sleep(length)
```

In order to update with each new track, I'm using a loop delayed by the number of seconds in the current track. When compiling, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\000\Downloads\pyfoobar\pyfoobar\playing.py", line 8, in <module>
    minute=int(length[0])*60
IndexError: string index out of range
```

There's probably something obvious I'm missing, but I can't find what's fixing the error, especially because the lines calculating the length will return the correct number of seconds.

Comment: What is the value stored in `length`? Can you print it?

Comment: For a song, say, 4:18, it will return 4:19. The final length line subtracts one second to correct for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `playRandom` is synchronous? You tested for `isPlaying` before calling `lengthOfTrack`, but maybe after calling `playRandom` (and before it finished executing) `isPlaying` is false, so `lengthOfTrack` will return something undefined. I have no experience with COM, so maybe I'm saying something stupid, but the first thing I'd try is to re-check for `isPlaying` again inside the loop.

Comment: I've tried setting it to simply an infinite loop (While(True)), it doesn't seem like it depends on the track playing.

Comment: @oracleCreeper but what if **no** track is playing? What will `lengthOfTrack` return? `"0:00"`? Your issue seems to be that `length` is an empty string in some moment, and my only guess is that happens when foobar is switching tracks (in response to your `playRandom` call). Try `print length` just after you created it.

Comment: I tried taking out the length calculation and setting the delay to a set time to test it. Somehow, this changes the track and artist to "check metadata". I feel like something in the loop itself might be causing issues, since they both work fine outside. I do agree though that the possible no length could cause a problem.

Comment: @oracleCreeper But have you confirmed or not that the track is playing? I can see you don't believe me, but I'm confident that's the most probable cause for the bug. In that case, the other methods (to return metadata) would have unexpected results too. Maybe if you called `time.sleep(1)` just after `playRandom()` that would give foobar enough time to change tracks.

Comment: I think I must have misspoken. I do believe that that's likely the bug, but there isn't really a way to test it easily. I'll try adding the delay at the beginning and see what I get.

Comment: The delay fixed the problem! You were right, it must have been the empty string. I did notice that having playRandom adds an additional track selection to foobar's next track, so I'll move that outside the loop for the initial song. Thanks for the help!